# Objective-C: Set UIWebView's ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I am trying to set the webview's scrollview using the code below but it disabled the scrolling/interaction of the webview.

```
[webView sizeToFit];
    webView.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    webView.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(375, rfqWeb.scrollView.contentSize.height + 700);
    rfqWeb.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the "scrollable size", I suggest to do:

```
- (void)setInsetsTop:(CGFloat)top bottom:(CGFloat)bottom {
    self.webview.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - bottom);

    [[self.webview scrollView] setContentInset:UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, 0, bottom, 0)];
}
```

I call it from another class

```
[htmlWebViewController setInsetsTop:0.0f bottom:44.0f];
```

If you use it in the same class just use

```
[self setInsetsTop:0.0f bottom:44.0f];
```

Comment: htmlWebViewController is an unknown receiver

Comment: Yes, as I said, I call it from another class, if you want to use inside the same classe, just use  [self setInsetsTop:0.0f bottom:44.0f];
I edited the first answer